# Как сделать, чтобы каждая буква в слове через одну (чётная) была чуть больше?

Tags: html, css

```css
.mor {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Л
  <span class="mor">а</span>
  в
  <span class="mor">а</span>
  н
  <span class="mor">д</span>
  а
</p>
```

Я так понимаю это можно сделать через псевдоклассы. Как?

Comment: А почему не устраивает текущий вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде как Adobe планировали продвинуть селектор `:nth-letter()`, но что-то никаких новостей нет, так что (пока?) браузеры такого не умеют. Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [nthEverything](https://github.com/FWeinb/nthEverything) — она добавит поддержку необходимых селекторов, автоматически разбирая текст на буквы ([пример использования](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpqNBO)), но, конечно, подготовить текст на стороне сервера будет куда производительнее.

```css
#letters:nth-letter(even){
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<p id="letters">Чётные буквы больше на 20%</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/FWeinb/nthEverything/master/jquery.nthEverything.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Решил вспомнить JS и написал свой велосипед: https://jsfiddle.net/ansx1cdf/. P. S. Хотя да, лучше сразу всё по символам разбирать и каждому символу давать класс ... Что-то я упустил этот момент :D